# Is it possible to find what is referencing a certain object?

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-7.0

Is there any way in .net 7 to trace what is holding references to a particular type or instance? in my code not in a profiler.

there were a lot of changes in instrumentation and diagnostics in .net 7 - I wonder if there is a way to programmatically find refs to a type and its instances - that I dynamically compile and load?

*I cant find a way to I unload it. Simple app I did as a baseline unloads its just fine. It seems the prod app holds refs to it that I cant see..*

Comment: I believe you can kinda-sorta do this if you take a dump of your process and load it into WinDbg with the correct set of extensions (I've never done this, but I'm pretty sure I watched (over the shoulder) when someone did this.  If I remember correctly, It's not a simple process.  You might try looking at some of the debugging blogs.  Don't forget that GC behavior may be radically different when running in Debug mode, compared to running a production build on a server.

Comment: yeah i was kinda-sorta trying to avoid that route :) hoped .net 7 have some magic tool like give access to gc handles and whatnot :) so far i need to be able to unload in any mode.. worry about prod later..

Comment: I don't know, maybe there's a nifty-cool way of doing this now.